# setState data updating one iteration late in parent - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

The setState data in child is updating one iteration late in parent. My goal is that any time a value changes in child component I get the new updated field plus all the old ones in parent. The log line in parent shows the state data, all fields, but 1 iteration late. That is if I write "A" in *Milestone Name* console prints empty now if update it to "B" is shows "A" in console that is previous iteration

**ConfigureCalenderForm.js (Parent Component)**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import MilestoneDetails from './MilestoneDetails';
import './ConfigureCalenderForm.css';

const ConfigureCalenderForm = () => {
  const milestoneDetailsChangeHandler = (milestoneDetails) => {
    console.log(milestoneDetails);
  };


  return (
    <div className='configure-calender__container'>
      <form>
        <MilestoneDetails
          onMilestoneDetailsUpdate={milestoneDetailsChangeHandler}
        />

        <div className='row configure-calender__actions'>
          <Button
            className='primary-blue small'
            icon={{
              color: '#fff',
              icon: 'checkMark',
              size: 'medium',
              isRequired: {},
            }}
            label='Save Milestone'
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ConfigureCalenderForm;
```

**MilestoneDetails.js (Child Component)**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './MilestoneDetails.css';

const MilestoneDetails = (props) => {
  const [enteredName, setEnteredName] = useState('');
  const [enteredDate, setEnteredDate] = useState('');
  const [enteredDescription, setEnteredDescription] = useState('');

  const nameChangedHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredName(event.target.value);
    const milestoneDetails = {
      enteredName: enteredName,
      enteredDate: new Date(enteredDate),
      enteredDescription: enteredDescription,
    };

    props.onMilestoneDetailsUpdate(milestoneDetails);
  };

  const dateChangedHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredDate(event.target.value);
    const milestoneDetails = {
      enteredName: enteredName,
      enteredDate: new Date(enteredDate),
      enteredDescription: enteredDescription,
    };

    props.onMilestoneDetailsUpdate(milestoneDetails);
  };

  const descriptionChangedHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredDescription(event.target.value);
    const milestoneDetails = {
      enteredName: enteredName,
      enteredDate: new Date(enteredDate),
      enteredDescription: enteredDescription,
    };

    props.onMilestoneDetailsUpdate(milestoneDetails);
  };

  return (
    <div className='milestone__controls'>
      <div className='milestone__row'>
        <div className='milestone__control'>
          <label>Milestone Name</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Please Enter'
            value={enteredName}
            onChange={nameChangedHandler}
          />
        </div>

        <div className='milestone__control'>
          <label>Milestone Date</label>
          <input
            type='date'
            placeholder='Please Select'
            value={enteredDate}
            onChange={dateChangedHandler}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className='milestone__row'>
        <div className='milestone__controlTextArea'>
          <label>Milestone Description</label>
          <textarea
            className='milestone__TextArea'
            placeholder='Please Enter'
            maxLength={'50'}
            value={enteredDescription}
            onChange={descriptionChangedHandler}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MilestoneDetails;
```

Answer (score 1):

yes that is how the state works . you call `setState` then react would schedule an update to compute what it needs in the next render, so through out the execution of the function - `dateChangeHandler` for example - you still see the old state, and to send the new state to the parent send the `event.target.value` instead of `enterdDate`.

Answer (score 0):

To update data in the parent component, we must be sure that you are using updated data from the child component, to do that we can use useEffect hook with a dependency of the updated data, and now inside useEffet set the state of the parent component.

Comment: Code example would be better.